# I need to change order of a sentence using css

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm a very beginner using a plugin in WooCommerce and the plugin that show a sentence before the price, and I need to invert its order.

Now is:

You can earn 2 points $100 (in a single line)

Where: "You can earn 2 points" is the message from `<span class="wc-pts-rwd-product-message">` and $100 is from `<span class="amount">`

The html is this:

```
<div class="single_variation">
    <span class="price">
    <span class="wc-pts-rwd-product-message">
    <span class="amount">$100</span>
    </span>
</div>
```

How should I write the css to make it show like:

**$100**
You can earn 2 points

First the price (amount) and than the message of points below the price.

I found that this is coming from the plugin so I can't change it  or updates will be compromised.

If I can get it done only by css?
Could somebody help me with this? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Which plugin are you using? I know you are using WooCommerce. I mean which extension. Is this a single variable product page? Is there a link you can provide to this page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pretty hacky way you can do it with `css` only:

```
.single_variation .price{
  display: inline-block;
  width: 180px;
}
.single_variation .wc-pts-rwd-product-message{
  float: right;
}
.single_variation .amount{
  float: left;
}
```

Tweak the 180px value depending on your font size. `css` is not too well suited to this task and it would be better to change the HTML flow if you can.

To do this in WordPress you'd need to find the template where this is outputted and overwrite it in your theme. This way your change won't be overwritten when the plugin updates. Below are some methods to get you started modifiying WordPress plugins without changing core code:

- Hooks and filters - http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/hooks-wordpress-actions-filters-examples
- Overwriting templates - https://docs.woothemes.com/document/template-structure/
- Modifying theme with a child theme - https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

A method of modifying css is to install the Jetpack plugin and activate their css module. Then in the WordPress admin area under `Appearance->Edit CSS` you'll be able to add your own `css` declarations that can overwrite original `css`.

Comment: Thanks James, but I can't change the theme files too, it will be lost with future updates, that is why my hope was to find a way using only the custom css of the theme.

Comment: I have thought that the plugin is taking the "amount", adding the "points message" and creating the entire message of "price" by it functions but I don't know a bit of php... just thoughts. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @M.Hatta It does, but you can overwrite or modify those functions using the correct WordPress techniques. Also, if an answer resolves your problem can you please mark it resolved and/or upvote it. It gives us reputation for answering and cleans up the question queue.

Comment: @M.Hatta Added some tips for modifying the code. The last tip about Jetpack will help with just modifying `css`.

Comment: I'm trying to solve this but still can't find a solution. I am using a child theme, so I can add custom css. I tried your code, but it changes the look of the price on the entire site.
I wish I could have a way to get the "amount" first, then the "message" next, only in this specific div "single_variation" using only css if it is possible.

Comment: @M.Hatta modified my answer, try that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this -

```html
 <div class="single_variation">
        <strong class="amount">$100</strong>
        <span class="wc-pts-rwd-product-message">You can earn<span class="price"> 1 </span> points</span>
    </div>
```